# How to change the colour of YAxis label of recharts in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I am working on a 2 y-axis chart. I want the Y-axis label having the same color with tick color. But I still not able to do it

```
<ComposedChart height={300} data={chart_data}>
    <CartesianGrid ... />
    <XAxis ..... />
    <YAxis .....
           label={{ .... fill:'#FDF652' }} />    #Fill here not working 
     <YAxis ....  
           label={{ .... fill:'#535184'}} />     #Fill here not working 
     <Tooltip ......... />

     <Area fill="#8884d8"/>           #Fill here working
     <Bar  fill="#535184" ..../>      #Fill here working
     <Legend ............ />
</ComposedChart>
```

When I add `fill` in `Area` and `Bar` it works and has color. But when I add `fill` in `<YAxis label>` it is not working

Comment: Canyou share the link of reproducible example for eg: CodeSandbox ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If by label you mean the axis title, the `fill` props should do the trick, but it must have a value, otherwise there is no text to color.
Just like:

```
<YAxis label={{ value: 'test', fill: 'red' }} />
```

In order to color the the tick lines and the tick labels, you can use the props `tick` and `tickLine` respectively, just like this:

```
<YAxis tick={{ fill: 'red' }} tickLine={{ stroke: 'red' }} />
```

That results in:

[image]